# Sort date by value In Xml c#

Tags: c#, xml

I'm trying to sort the date-tags in my XML by value:

```
var noteElements = xDoc.Root.Descendants("Note").OrderBy(o => (DateTime)o.Element("date")).ToList();

foreach (XElement noteEl in noteElements)
{
    string noteDateValue = noteEl.Element("date").Value;
    noteEl.ReplaceWith(new XElement("notedate", noteEl, new XAttribute("date", noteDateValue)));
}
```

That doesn't work. The dates are not sorted as expected.

**XML:**

```
<Root>
 <Notes>
    <notedate date="date here"><Note>
    <date>1997-07-04T00:00:00</date>
    </Note></notedate>
    <notedate date="date here"><Note>
      <date>1997-06-04T00:00:00</date>
    </Note></notedate>
</Notes>
</Root>
```

Anyone who can explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: change `.OrderBy(o => (DateTime)o.Element("date")` to `.OrderBy(o => (DateTime)o.Element("date").Value`?

Comment: @Johan: I only get the error: Cannot convert type string to System.DateTime

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're replacing each `Note` element with a `notedate` element. The order in which you perform that replacement is irrelevant.

It sounds like you *actually* want something like:

```
var notes = doc.Root.Element("Notes");
notes.ReplaceNodes(notes.Elements()
                        .OrderBy(x => (DateTime) x.Element("date"))
                        .Select(x => new XElement("notedate",
                            new XAttribute("date", "date here"),
                            x));
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Can you please explain the code?

Comment: @Bryan: Well which bit of the code don't you understand? I'm replacing the entire contents of the `Notes` element with the result of the "query" which orders the `Note` elements by date and wraps them in a `notedate` element. As for your second question, see what you can do for yourself - hint: replace `"date here"` with an expression to get the date as a `DateTime` based on `x`...

Comment: Im very new to C#, but thank you :). I solved my second problem like this: x.Element("date").Value Is that a valid way to solve It?

Comment: @Bryan: Well I would cast to `DateTime` instead, as I have in `OrderBy` - but using `Value` works as well, given that you've already effectively validated that it's okay...